# Get auditlogs for a specific user through object id or principal name

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying tofind who issued a guest user from a given object id.

[image]

As far as I know this can only be found through audit logs. However I cannot seem to find auditlogs from a given user only. I tried:

```
var directoryAudits = await graphClient.AuditLogs.DirectoryAudits.Request().Filter($"targetResources/any(c:c/id eq '{id}'").GetAsync();
```

But I get an bad request exception. Any pointers to get audit logs for a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that filter query is missing right bracket `)` for `any`

```
var directoryAudits = await graphClient.AuditLogs.
DirectoryAudits
.Request()
.Filter($"targetResources/any(c:c/id eq '{id}')")
.GetAsync();
```